# unable to load the csv file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv

I am trying to load the data from a file called stores.csv but unable to load.
Here I am posting my code and the csv file name is called read.csv so please help me to solve the issue.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Read Data from Text File into Objects and Output as Table</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquery-csv.googlecode.com/git/src/jquery.csv.js"></script>

<body>
    <h1>Pull data from CSV file into an object and output as table</h1>
    <div class="result">
        <table id="theResult" border="1"></table>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.get('stores.csv', function (theData) {
            var data = $.csv.toObjects(theData);
            var theHtml = createTable(data);
            $('#theResult').html(theHtml);
        });
    });

    function createTable(data) {
        var html = '';

        if (data[0].constructor === Object) {
            html += '<tr>\r\n';
            for (var item in data[0]) {
                html += '<th>' + item + '</th>\r\n';
            }
            html += '</tr>\r\n';

            for (var row in data) {
                html += '<tr>\r\n';
                for (var item in data[row]) {
                    html += '<td>' + data[row][item] + '</td>\r\n';
                }
                html += '</tr>\r\n';
            }
        }
        return html;
    }
</script>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: *"unable to load"* tells us little of value that we can troubleshoot from without having to ask 20 questions

Comment: There could be any number of reasons this doesn't work, so without context this is too broad for anyone to help you with effectively. Could you at least check the console to see if there's any errors, and let us know what they say

Comment: @JeremyThille Maybe i didnt get your point, i think he can using a `$.get()` request a file could be read either `.csv` or `.txt` if it is on the same domain?

Comment: Failed to load resource (jQuery.csv.js) which I mentioned in script tag at line 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url that you have used for the `jquery.csv.js` does not exist anymore and throws a `404`. So your error is at the  line

`$.csv.toObjects(theData);`

you should change the url to this `CDN`  link

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.8.3/jquery.csv.min.js

so basically your tag changes from

`<script src="http://jquery-csv.googlecode.com/git/src/jquery.csv.js"></script>`

to

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.8.3/jquery.csv.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Glad to help. Cheers!